# How to cancel a Select in RX if it is not finished before the next event arrives

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have the following setup

```
IObservable<Data> source = ...;

source
    .Select(data=>VeryExpensiveOperation(data))
    .Subscribe(data=>Console.WriteLine(data));
```

Normally the events come seperated by a reasonable time frame.
Imagine a user updating a text box in a form. Our `VeryExpensiveOperation`
might take 5 seconds to complete and whilst it does an hour glass
is displayed on the screen.

However if during the 5 seconds the user updates the textbox again
I would want to send a cancelation to the current `VeryExpensiveOperation`
before the new one starts.

I would imagine a scenario like

```
source
    .SelectWithCancel((data, cancelToken)=>VeryExpensiveOperation(data, token))
    .Subscribe(data=>Console.WriteLine(data));
```

So every time the lambda is called is is called with a cancelToken which can be
used to manage canceling a `Task`. However now we are mixing Task, CancelationToken and RX. 
Not quite sure how to fit it all together. Any suggestions.

**Bonus Points** for figuring out how to test the operator using XUnit :)

**FIRST ATTEMPT**

```
    public static IObservable<U> SelectWithCancelation<T, U>( this IObservable<T> This, Func<CancellationToken, T, Task<U>> fn )
    {
        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        return This
            .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)
            .Select(v=>{
                tokenSource.Cancel();
                tokenSource=new CancellationTokenSource();
                return new {tokenSource.Token, v};
            })
            .SelectMany(o=>Observable.FromAsync(()=>fn(o.Token, o.v)));
    }
```

Not tested yet. I'm hoping that a task that does not complete generates an IObservable that completes without firing any `OnNext` events.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to model `VeryExpensiveOperation` as an cancellable asynchronous thing.  Either a `Task` or an `IObservable`.  I'll assume it is a task with a `CancellationToken`:

```
Task<TResult> VeryExpensiveOperationAsync<TSource, TResult>(TSource item, CancellationToken token);
```

Then you do it like so:

```
source
    .Select(item => Observable.DeferAsync(async token =>
    {
        // do not yield the observable until after the operation is completed
        // (ie do not just do VeryExpensiveOperation(...).ToObservable())
        // because DeferAsync() will dispose of the token source as soon
        // as you provide the observable (instead of when the observable completes)
        var result = await VeryExpensiveOperationAsync(item, token);
        return Observable.Return(result);
    })
    .Switch();
```

The `Select` just creates a deferred observable that, when subscribed, will create a token and kick off the operation.  If the observable is unsubscribed before the operation finishes, the token will be cancelled.

The `Switch` subscribes to each new observable that comes out of `Select`, unsubscribing from the previous observable it was subscribed to.

This has the effect you want.

P.S. this is easily testable.  Just provide a mock source and a mock `VeryExpensiveOperation` that uses a `TaskCompletetionSource` provided by the unit test so the unit test can control exactly when new source items are produced and when tasks are completed.  Something like this:

```
void SomeTest()
{
    // create a test source where the values are how long
    // the mock operation should wait to do its work.
    var source = _testScheduler.CreateColdObservable<int>(...);

    // records the actions (whether they completed or canceled)
    List<bool> mockActionsCompleted = new List<bool>();
    var resultStream = source.SelectWithCancellation((token, delay) =>
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        var tokenRegistration = new SingleAssignmentDisposable();

        // schedule an action to complete the task
        var d = _testScheduler.ScheduleRelative(delay, () =>
        {
           mockActionsCompleted.Add(true);
           tcs.SetResult("done " + delay);
           // stop listening to the token
           tokenRegistration.Dispose();
        });

        // listen to the token and cancel the task if the token signals
        tokenRegistration.Disposable = token.Register(() =>
        {
           mockActionsCompleted.Add(false);
           tcs.TrySetCancelled();
           // cancel the scheduled task
           d.Dispose();
        });

        return tcs.Task;
    });

    // subscribe to resultStream
    // start the scheduler
    // assert the mockActionsCompleted has the correct sequence
    // assert the results observed were what you expected.
}
```

You might run into trouble using `testScheduler.Start()` due to the new actions scheduled dynamically.  a while loop with `testScheduler.AdvanceBy(1)` might work better.

Comment: I don't quite understand where the ``token`` is cancelled. Is it done automagically when Switch unsubscribes from the previous inner observable?

Comment: `DeferAsync` creates the token when the observable is subscribed.  It then cancels the token if the observable is unsubscribed before the Task produces the *real* observable (letting you know you do not need to keep working to produce the real observable).  `Switch` keeps subscribing to the new observable that arrives and unsubscribing from the previous, which triggers the cancellation of the previous.

Comment: I am having trouble writing a mock VeryExpensiveOperation. Problem is I have to use Task.Run to create it which put's it on another thread out of context of the TestScheduler. Then I don't get correct results.

Comment: I added an example of what I was thinking.

Comment: For creating a Task which cannot follow the boiler plate rules: i.e. must run on specific thread, look at TaskCompletionSource, and rather use a class derived from RX.NET's IScheduler than TaskScheduler. TaskCompletionSource essentially allows you to create a Task from any operation. IScheduler can guarantee which thread you run on more deterministically than TaskScheduler, i.e. EventLoopScheduler.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use a Throttle?

http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc30

> Throttle stops the flow of events until no more events are produced for a specified period of time. For example, if you throttle a TextChanged event of a textbox to .5 seconds, no events will be passed until the user has stopped typing for .5 seconds. This is useful in search boxes where you do not want to start a new search after every keystroke, but want to wait until the user pauses.

```
SearchTextChangedObservable = Observable.FromEventPattern<TextChangedEventArgs>(this.textBox, "TextChanged");
_currentSubscription = SearchTextChangedObservable.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.5)).ObserveOnDispatcher
```

Comment: You got it round the wrong way.  The events don't come too quick. No need to throttle. The processing is very expensive and should be cancelled if new data is available.

Comment: Actually, I meant throttle before starting the expensive processing, so that we only run it when we know it wil have time to complete. However I can now see that this would just be a primitive estimation of how long it needs to complete, compared to Brandon's implementation.